# Fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on MSI GS40-6QE-Phantom - Both wifi and wired connection not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, internet

I just bought a MSI GS40-6QE-Phantom laptop which came with Free Dos. I managed to install Ubuntu 14.04 on it, and in the process wiped out anything that was on the disk. 
Now, I cannot get the laptop to connect to ethernet or wifi (fyi, it uses killer gb lan and killer wireless 1525). I have looked up other similar questions involving issues with killer products, but I am stuck.

First of all this laptop has no internet connection whatsoever, so I cannot update or install build-essentials. Also, for some reason any command that accesses PCI such as lspci command only freezes the terminal.

Is there any way to get the necessary drivers without internet connection?
Also, I get soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for xxs whenever I try to shutdown the laptop as well. Did installation go wrong? Or is it because I did not get any updates while installing. I'm lost. Please help.

---

Also I accidentally deleted the manufacturer recovery partition while installing Ubuntu.... The seller told me the partition was for drivers and not to delete it, but... I did not know it was for recovery also.

Comment: Are you referring to Windows drivers to help get it back to normal? http://www.msi.com/product/notebook/support/GS40-6QE-Phantom.html#down-driver&Win10%2064 Also, where have you managed to buy the GS40? You're the first person I've heard of being able to actually get hold of one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to get your laptop working, you need the latest Linux kernel available.
This issue seems to be fixed in Ubuntu 15.10: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184

Comment: I'm trying to get ubuntu 16.04 working on my msi gs40 phantom and I noticed it still doesn't seem to support the killer wifi.  Oddly enough it will detect my networks via wifi, but when I put in the password it just fails to connect each time.

Comment: Looks like wifi does work after all.  I'm not sure what eventually made it function for me as I have been using several different kernel options to try and get this thing functional.  I am still, however, unable to get ubuntu to install on my msi gs40.  I am able to get the live USB installer to run and allow it to download updates now though. I have tried several combinations of: nomodeset idle=nomwait and finally libata.force=noncq